# Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails PHP y MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7

actualmente tengo un sistema de encuestas, el cual esta por usuario que contesta la encuesta y otro usuario administrador que hace las preguntas y las publica y finaliza

en la estructura de mi base de datos he agregado un campo a la tabla que guarda el usuario que respondió, la pregunta que respondio y la respuesta que dio, sin embargo al querer guardar me salen 2 errores

el primero a nivel de base de datos me genera este error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sistema_encuestasv1`.`usuarios_encuestas`, CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opcion`) REFERENCES `opciones` (`id_opcion`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_sondeo\usuario\procesar.php:79 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_sondeo\usuario\procesar.php(79): mysqli->query('INSERT INTO usu...') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sistema_sondeo\usuario\procesar.php on line 79
```

Y el segundo error es en el código PHP el cual es el siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que es del campo que acabo de agregar, la verdad no se porque me genera ambos errores

comparto estructura de las tablas

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 4.8.0
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Servidor: 127.0.0.1
-- Tiempo de generación: 23-07-2018 a las 04:55:17
-- Versión del servidor: 10.1.31-MariaDB
-- Versión de PHP: 7.2.4

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Base de datos: `sistema_encuestasv1`
--

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `encuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `encuestas` (
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fecha_final` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `opciones`
--

CREATE TABLE `opciones` (
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `preguntas`
--

CREATE TABLE `preguntas` (
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `resultados`
--

CREATE TABLE `resultados` (
  `id_resultado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_pregunta` (
  `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_spanish2_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish2_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`, `nombre`, `descripcion`) VALUES
(1, 'Selección múltiple', 'Se podrá escoger solo una opción\r\nelemento input type radio'),
(2, 'Desplegable', 'Se podrá escoger una opción\r\nElemento select y option'),
(3, 'Casilla de verificación', 'Se podrá escoger más de una opción\r\ninput type checkbox'),
(4, 'Texto', 'Se almacenara la respuesta');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

CREATE TABLE `tipo_usuario` (
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `nombre` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Volcado de datos para la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--

INSERT INTO `tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`, `nombre`) VALUES
(1, 'Administrador'),
(2, 'Usuario');


-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `porcentaje_participacion` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


INSERT INTO `usuarios` (`id_usuario`,`clave`,`nombres`,`apellidos`,`email`,`id_tipo_usuario`,`porcentaje_participacion`) VALUES
('admin', 'admin', 'Administrador', 'AD', 'admin@correo.com', '1', '0'),
('303167', '123', 'Marco', 'Chavez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '50'),
('301663', '123', 'Mauren', 'Martinez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303344', '123', 'Neidy', 'Osorto', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303203', '123', 'Jorge', 'Martinez', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '10'),
('303314', '123', 'Sonia', 'Sorto', 'admin@correo.com', '2', '20');

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios_encuestas` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

--
-- Índices para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Indices de la tabla `encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `encuestas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_opcion`),
  ADD KEY `id_pregunta` (`id_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_pregunta`),
  ADD KEY `id_encuesta` (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_resultado`),
  ADD KEY `id_opcion` (`id_opcion`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_pregunta`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_tipo_pregunta`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`);

--
-- Indices de la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios_encuestas`
  ADD KEY `id_usuario` (`id_usuario`),
  ADD KEY `id_encuesta` (`id_encuesta`),
  ADD KEY `id_opcion` (`id_opcion`);

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de las tablas volcadas
--

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `encuestas`
  MODIFY `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  MODIFY `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  MODIFY `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  MODIFY `id_resultado` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_pregunta`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_pregunta`
  MODIFY `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=5;

--
-- AUTO_INCREMENT de la tabla `tipo_usuario`
--
ALTER TABLE `tipo_usuario`
  MODIFY `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, AUTO_INCREMENT=3;

--
-- Restricciones para tablas volcadas
--

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `opciones`
--
ALTER TABLE `opciones`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `opciones_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_pregunta`) REFERENCES `preguntas` (`id_pregunta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `preguntas`
--
ALTER TABLE `preguntas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `preguntas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_pregunta`) REFERENCES `tipo_pregunta` (`id_tipo_pregunta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `preguntas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_encuesta`) REFERENCES `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `resultados`
--
ALTER TABLE `resultados`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `resultados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opcion`) REFERENCES `opciones` (`id_opcion`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `usuarios`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo_usuario`) REFERENCES `tipo_usuario` (`id_tipo_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

--
-- Filtros para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--
ALTER TABLE `usuarios_encuestas`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_usuario`) REFERENCES `usuarios` (`id_usuario`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_encuesta`) REFERENCES `encuestas` (`id_encuesta`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `usuarios_encuestas_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_opcion`) REFERENCES `opciones` (`id_opcion`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Y este es el código de mi PHP para guardar la respuesta ingresada

```
<?php

    require ('../conexion.php');

    $id_encuesta = $_POST['id_encuesta'];
    $id_opcion = isset($_GET['id_opcion']) ? $_GET['id_opcion'] : 0;


    $query10 = "SELECT * FROM encuestas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $resultado10 = $con->query($query10);
    $row10 = $resultado10->fetch_assoc();

    $ids = array();

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/Logo-fis.png">


  <title>Procesar</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
     
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="color: #fff">
          
            <?php   
            session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
                echo "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['u_usuario'] . "\t";

                echo "<a href='../cerrar_sesion.php' class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left: 10px'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
                } else {
                  header("Location: ../index.php");
                }
           ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <center>
        <div style="margin-top: 50px"></div>
        <?php


        $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

        $query5 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_encuestas WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
        $resultado5 = $con->query($query5);
        $tamaño = $resultado5->num_rows;

        if ($tamaño > 0) {
            echo "Ya respondiste la encuesta";
            echo "<br/>";
        } else {
            
            $query6 = "INSERT INTO usuarios_encuestas (id_usuario, id_encuesta, id_opcion) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$id_encuesta', '$id_opcion')";
            $resultado6 = $con->query($query6);

            if ($row10['estado'] == '1') {
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {

                    if (isset($_POST[$i])) {
                        $ids[$i] = $_POST[$i];

                        $id = $ids[$i];

                        $query2 = "SELECT id_opcion, id_pregunta, valor FROM opciones WHERE id_opcion = '$ids[$i]'";
                        $resultado2 = $con->query($query2);

                        if ($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $id_opcion = $row2['id_opcion'];
                            $query3 = "INSERT INTO resultados (id_opcion) 
                            VALUES ('$id_opcion')";
                            $resultado3 = $con->query($query3);
                            if ($resultado3) {
                                echo "Resultado ingresado";
                                echo "<br/>";
                            } else { 
                                echo "Error al ingresar resultado";
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "<div style='margin-top: 50px;'>ERROR!<br/>La encuesta se encuentra cerrada</div>";
            }
        }

         ?>

        <br/>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php">VOLVER</a>
    </center>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

este es el código del archivo procesar.php

```
<?php

    require ('../conexion.php');

    $id_encuesta = $_POST['id_encuesta'];
    $id_opcion = $_GET['id_opcion'];


    $query10 = "SELECT * FROM encuestas WHERE id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
    $resultado10 = $con->query($query10);
    $row10 = $resultado10->fetch_assoc();

    $ids = array();

 ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Favicon - FIS -->
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../imagenes/Logo-fis.png">


  <title>Procesar</title>
</head>
<body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">Sistema de Encuestas</a>
     
      <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navb">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
    

      <!--NAVBAR-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navb">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        </ul>
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" style="color: #fff">
          
            <?php   
            session_start();
                if (isset($_SESSION['u_usuario']) && isset($_SESSION['id_usuario'])) {
                echo "Bienvenido " . $_SESSION['u_usuario'] . "\t";

                echo "<a href='../cerrar_sesion.php' class='btn btn-danger' style='margin-left: 10px'>Cerrar Sesión</a>";
                } else {
                  header("Location: ../index.php");
                }
           ?>
        </form>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <center>
        <div style="margin-top: 50px"></div>
        <?php


        $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];

        $query5 = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_encuestas WHERE id_usuario = '$id_usuario' AND id_encuesta = '$id_encuesta'";
        $resultado5 = $con->query($query5);
        $tamaño = $resultado5->num_rows;

        if ($tamaño > 0) {
            echo "Ya respondiste la encuesta";
            echo "<br/>";
        } else {
            
            $query6 = "INSERT INTO usuarios_encuestas (id_usuario, id_encuesta, id_opcion) VALUES ('$id_usuario', '$id_encuesta', '$id_opcion')";
            $resultado6 = $con->query($query6);

            if ($row10['estado'] == '1') {
                for ($i = 1; $i <= 100; $i++) {

                    if (isset($_POST[$i])) {
                        $ids[$i] = $_POST[$i];

                        $id = $ids[$i];

                        $query2 = "SELECT id_opcion, id_pregunta, valor FROM opciones WHERE id_opcion = '$ids[$i]'";
                        $resultado2 = $con->query($query2);

                        if ($row2 = $resultado2->fetch_assoc()) {
                            $id_opcion = $row2['id_opcion'];
                            $query3 = "INSERT INTO resultados (id_opcion) 
                            VALUES ('$id_opcion')";
                            $resultado3 = $con->query($query3);
                            if ($resultado3) {
                                echo "Resultado ingresado";
                                echo "<br/>";
                            } else { 
                                echo "Error al ingresar resultado";
                            } 
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                echo "<div style='margin-top: 50px;'>ERROR!<br/>La encuesta se encuentra cerrada</div>";
            }
        }

         ?>

        <br/>
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php">VOLVER</a>
    </center>

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="../js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Si alguien me ayudar una sugerencia de como resolver ambos errores

Comment: ¿Y el contenido del archivo `procesar.php`? Es en ese archivo donde tienes la consulta SQL que está lanzando ese error. Es muy probable que estés haciendo una actualización o inserción que no cumpla las restricciones de claves foráneas, pero necesitamos el código para confirmarlo.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Listo ahora ya lo edite y agregue el código del archivo procesar.php

Comment: Para empezar, tu código sufre los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL). Te recomiendo usar consultas preparadas o, como mínimo, escapar todo lo que concatenes a tu SQL. Para continuar, no veo el formulario que envía los datos a `procesar.php` o el código Javascript que genera los capos del formulario y/o realiza el envío. Por último, parece que no estás recibiendo adecuadamente los datos del formulario y por eso no se cumple la existencia de los registros en las tablas foráneas.

Answer (score 1):

En esta línea es donde salta el error "Undefined array key id_opcion":

```
$id_opcion = $_GET['id_opcion'];
```

Eso significa que en $_GET no existe esa clave, por lo que supongo que probablemente tengas que usar `$_POST['id_opcion']` para corregir el funcionamiento (de hecho, en la línea anterior estás obteniendo un valor de $_POST).

Luego el error de mysql "Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails" te aparece justamente porque `$id_opcion` te ha quedado sin valor y entonces falla la relación con la tabla `opciones` al intentar guardarlo en `usuarios_encuestas`.

Hay otros problemas de inyección de SQL que deberías revisar, tal como ya te han indicado en otros comentarios.

Comment: Esta respuesta está basada en mi conjetura, pero como no ha compartido el código HTML del formulario es probable que se esté mandando por GET ese parámetro (agregándolo a la URL, en ambos PHP se espera que esté presente en el código) y que el error sea otro. Esperaremos a que comparta el formulario para poder averiguar el motivo real (y no una suposición) del problema.